# Spark metrics sink doesn't expose executor's metrics

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, hadoop2, metrics, graphite

I'm using Spark on YARN with

Ambari `2.7.4`
HDP Standalone `3.1.4`
Spark `2.3.2`
Hadoop `3.1.1`
Graphite on Docker `latest`

I was trying to get Spark metrics with Graphite sink following [this tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Monitoring-Spark-2-performance-via-Grafana-in-Ambari-Metrics/ta-p/248991).

Advanced spark2-metrics-properties in Ambari are:

```
driver.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
executor.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
worker.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
master.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
*.sink.graphite.host=ap-test-m.c.gcp-ps.internal
*.sink.graphite.port=2003
*.sink.graphite.protocol=tcp
*.sink.graphite.period=10
*.sink.graphite.unit=seconds
*.sink.graphite.prefix=app-test
*.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

Spark submit:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/hadoop/conf/; spark-submit --class com.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 spark-app.jar /data
```

As a result I'm only getting `driver` metrics.

Also, I was trying to add `metrics.properties` to `spark-submit` command together with global spark metrics props, but that didn't help.

And finally, I tried conf in `spark-submit` and in java `SparkConf`:

```
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.driver.sink.graphite.class"="org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink" 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.executor.sink.graphite.class"="org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink" 
--conf "worker.sink.graphite.class"="org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink"
--conf "master.sink.graphite.class"="org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink"
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.host"="host" 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.port"=2003 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.period"=10 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.unit"=seconds 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.graphite.prefix"="app-test" 
--conf "spark.metrics.conf.*.source.jvm.class"="org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource"
```

But that didn't help either.

`CSVSink` also gives only driver metrics.

**UPD**

When I submit job in `cluster` mode - I'm getting the same metrics as in `Spark History Server`. But the `jvm` metrics are still absent.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to a dated question, but maybe it will help.

Seems like executors do not have `metrics.properties` file on their filesystems.
One way to confirm this would be to look at the executor logs:

```
2020-01-16 10:00:10 ERROR MetricsConfig:91 - Error loading configuration file metrics.properties
java.io.FileNotFoundException: metrics.properties (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsConfig.loadPropertiesFromFile(MetricsConfig.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsConfig.initialize(MetricsConfig.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.<init>(MetricsSystem.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$.createMetricsSystem(MetricsSystem.scala:233)
```

To fix this on yarn pass two parameters to spark-submit:

```
$ spark-submit \
    --files metrics.properties \
    --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties
```

The `--files` option ensures that files specified in the option will be shared to executors.

The `spark.metrics.conf` option specifies a custom file location for the metrics.

Another way to fix the issue would be to place the metrics.properties file into `$SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties` on both the driver and executor before starting the job.

More on metrics here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html